# iOS-5 error in switching Views

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, ios5

I am trying to switch views on button press event, but when i press the button to switch the view from firstview to second. It shows the secondView for a sec or so and then a blank page appears. Im new to iOS programming so not getting what might be the issue.

Here is my code :

```
- (IBAction)okPressed:(id)sender {

AppDelegate *mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
shipView = [mainDelegate.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:shipView animated:YES];
```

The UIStoryBoard is instantiated in AppDelegate class. When the okPressed Method is invoked the SecondViewController is not loaded.

Comment: are you sure you are not dismissing the view as soon as it appears?

Comment: Yes , i m not dismissing the view. the above is the only code that i have in my method to switch views

Comment: Is there a way around to solve this issue

Comment: without seeing more code it is not possible to say anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard alloc / init will not do anything.  You need to either use `initWithNibName:bundle:` using the filename of your XIB, or `UIStoryboard`'s `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` using the identifier of the controller that you defined in the storyboard file.